# Interface in Object incompatible with GWT

Tags: java, gwt, interface

We are having some problems with GWT and some objects with interfaces.

This is an example:

```
public class Car implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 3678962348416518107L;

    String model;
    String color;
    CarID id;
}
```

In this case, CarID is an interface, which apparently is not supported by GWT.

Is there any solution other than changing the attribute type?

Thank you.

Comment: I'm using interfaces all the time in GWT classes. What exactly is the problem?

Comment: It should be Compatible over GWT-RPC unless it is not Serializable. Or it has some logic client-specific ran on server side. Or you are trying to send this object over REST? Specify.

Comment: What is `CarID` defined as? Is it in the client or shared packages so GWT can see it?

Answer (score -1):

try this:

```
public class Car implements IsSerializable {
    public Car(){}//Public constructor with no arguments (required for RPC)

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 3678962348416518107L;

    String model;
    String color;
    CarID id;
}
```

Also Make sure CarID extends IsSerializable or Serializable.

Hope this helps

Comment: You don't have to define this constructor, as it's implicit if there isn't any constructor in the class.

Comment: Oh yes you're right my bad. Then It must be the CarID interface not extending serializable.